# Sourcecode not found by Javac - windows

Tags: javac

I am new to java programming and I am learning the basics. 
I am trying to use the java compiler (javac) via the windows Command Prompt for running a first "Hello World!" program. These are the steps I undertook:

1) I have created a file with Notepad with the following code:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] argumente) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

2) I saved it as Hello.java in the following folders/ directories:

> C:\Users\Ema\eclipse-workspace\classes

3) I opened the Windows 10 Command Prompt and inputted the following code:

> C:\Users\Ema>javac -Xlint:all Hello.java

unfortunately I get this answer back when I "enter" the code line:

> error: file not found: Hello.java
>    Usage: javac  
>    use --help for a list of possible options

Could you please help me with some tips on how to run the program?
I have also already tried to give the targeted path via the javac -cp function, but I get always the same type of error.

Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe in notepad you saved it as Hello.txt.java  You need to be careful that notepad doesn't put the txt extension on the file. Really you should CD to the directory you are running javac from and run the DIR command to list files. Also make sure windows isn't hiding extensions(change that windows setting from its default). And make sure in notepad that when you save things you either put quotes around the filename, or you choose "save as type(all files)" so it doesn't put .txt after it

Comment: Do `C:\Users\Ema\eclipse-workspace\classes>javac Hello.java<ENTER>`

Comment: you need to go to the directory where your source file is ^

Comment: @barlop Thank you
txt ext removed!
I tried to CD to directory I am running Javac from with:
    C:\Users\Ema>CD>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin
but I get
    Access is denied.
I have also tried to CD to:
     C:\Users\Ema>CD>eclipse-workspace\classes
but here too
    Access is denied
In my Com. Prompt I have as default C:\Users\Ema> and cannot remove the >, so, using your suggestion, I entered:
    C:\Users\Ema>eclipse-workspace\classes>javac Hello.java
get:
'eclipse-workspace\classes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You shouldn't type ">"  it's there anyway. When you open a cmd prompt it should say `C:\Users\Ema>`  then type 'CD \<ENTER>' (i.e. hit c, then d, then space, then backslash, then press enter),   and then it should go to C:\>  now type `md blah` that makes a directory called blah.  Now do `C:\>cd blah<ENTER>` then it should say `C:\blah>`  then put Hello.java in there, and do `C:\blah>javac Hello.java<ENTER>` like https://i.imgur.com/94O4zbs.png  and then hopefully you will get no error then do `C:\blah>java Hello<ENTER>`

Comment: @barlop 
thank you! it worked and and I could understand better how the com. prompt works too.

Comment: No problem. Another command to know that is very useful and important is `dir`  so e.g. `C:\blah>dir<ENTER>` that will show you the files in the current directory.  As for CD, CD stands for "change directory".  You can also use tab, do  `cd \progr<tab>` and it will autocomplete to `cd \program files" then you can hit 'enter'.  `dir /?` will show you useful options with dir. like dir /a and dir /od and dir /os.  Also  if you type `help` it lists some commands, some are useful, some not so much.

Comment: Also, the program files directory and some other directories are read only, even C:\ is read only.  so even from windows you can't normally create a file there. So making a directory e.g. `C:\blah` is good 'cos it's easy to get to and you have full read/write access to it. You could've done it creating a folder  `C:\Users\Ema\Desktop\abcd` but it's easier to CD to `c:\blah`  (folder and directory is the same thing.. folder is just the modern name)

Comment: @Barlop
Very grateful for these additional information. I knew Help and through it I have got also to use DIR and CD already, but I did not know the syntax for letting these functions work. With your support now I have got that first you point at the folder (if necessary create even a new one) via the written path and then I can let the function run with Enter. Tks again

Comment: No prob.  see http://www.vfrazee.com/ms-dos/6.22/help/ that's the ancient official help that was available on the command line..but put online. See for example click 'dir' and then click it and click examples you will see syntax from there. (there are some differences between that - real DOS, its commands), and windows command line commands but the basic commands are the same.  I just found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands  that's exactly windows command line commands with examples